# Undecidable functional dependencies

Tags: haskell

I'm reading through [Clowns to the left of me, Jokers to the right](http://strictlypositive.org/CJ.pdf) and playing around with the Dissection class, and I came across a coverage condition error. Code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
import Data.Bifunctor
import GHC.Generics

data Add2 p q x y = L2 (p x y) | R2 (q x y)

instance (Bifunctor p, Bifunctor q) => Bifunctor (Add2 p q) where
  bimap f g (L2 p) = L2 (bimap f g p)
  bimap f g (R2 q) = R2 (bimap f g q)

class (Functor p, Bifunctor p') => Diss p p' | p -> p' where

instance (Diss p p', Diss q q') => Diss (p :+: q) (Add2 p' q')
```

GHC error message:

```
cj.hs:13:10: error:
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘Diss (p :+: q) (Add2 p' q')’
        The coverage condition fails in class ‘Diss’
          for functional dependency: ‘p -> p'’
        Reason: lhs type ‘p :+: q’ does not determine rhs type ‘Add2 p' q'’
        Un-determined variables: p', q'
        Using UndecidableInstances might help
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Diss (p :+: q) (Add2 p' q')’
   |
13 | instance (Diss p p', Diss q q') => Diss (p :+: q) (Add2 p' q')
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm struggling to understand the reason given: I feel that the type `p :+: q` should determine the rhs type because of the dependencies `p -> p'` and `q -> q'` implied by the constraints `Diss p p'` and `Diss q q'`. Enabling UndecidableInstances does remove the error, but I'd like to understand why it's necessary in this case.

Comment: [Here is a paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/jfp06.pdf) that claims to describe the coverage condition and other details about fundeps.  Your question is making me read it :-p

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a read

Comment: For future readers seeing this, type families are a much better way of getting similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GHC documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/instances.html#instance-termination-rules) has this to say about a similar scenario:

> ```
> class Mul a b c | a b -> c where
>   (.*.) :: a -> b -> c
>
> instance Mul Int Int Int where (.*.) = (*)
> instance Mul Int Float Float where x .*. y = fromIntegral x * y
> instance Mul a b c => Mul a [b] [c] where x .*. v = map (x.*.) v
> ```

(Answerer's note: as with your example, you might think here that in the `Mul a b c => Mul a [b] [c]` instance, since `a b` determines `c`, it ought to also be the case that `a [b]` clearly determines `[c]`.)

> The third instance declaration does not obey the coverage condition; and indeed the (somewhat strange) definition:
>
> ```
> f = \ b x y -> if b then x .*. [y] else y
> ```
>
> makes instance inference go into a loop, because it requires the constraint `Mul a [b] b`.

So the coverage condition is explicitly about ruling out cases like yours that *look* benign but may potentially not be.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much.